# What is the best way to implement an SQL Trigger that adds 1 to a column in Table_A if a record is inserted in Table_B

Tags: sql, mysql, automation, triggers, logic

So, I have a `company` table with one column in it called `number of employees`. This `company` table has a primary key `id` that appears as the `company_id` foreign key in the `employees` table. I'm writing a trigger that adds or subtracts 1 to the `number_of_employees` column in the `company` table if a new record of an employee from a particular company is inserted or removed from the `employees` table.

Before we proceed, the `number_of_employees` column is not included in the field list when inserting into the `company` table because it is set to have a default value of 0 so that these triggers can take effect behind the curtains.

Here is the trigger I wrote for when an employee gets inserted

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `movie_production_companies`.`employees_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `employees` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.company_id = company.id THEN
    SET company.number_of_employees = company.number_of_employees + 1;
    END IF;
END
```

and when an employee gets removed

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `movie_production_companies`.`employees_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `employees` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF company.id = OLD.company_id THEN
    SET company.number_of_employees = company.number_of_employees - 1;
    END IF;
END
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'company' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

and i have been lost since

Comment: I'd consider a view instead, for the number of employees.

Comment: `IF NEW.company_id = company.id` - the server does not know what is `company` in this statement (this is not a query, and there is no FROM clause).

Comment: @jarlh merry christmas to you and your support sytem. you were right. and i got to use views instead of triggers to answer the question